# Hyperloop error when processing Cocoapods dependencies

Tags: cocoapods, appcelerator, appcelerator-hyperloop, hyperloop, appc-hyperloop

After downloading the hyperloop-examples files, and running `appc ti build -p ios`, I get errors when Hyperloop finds the CocoaPods dependencies.
The exact error text is:

> [ERROR] An error occurred during build after 3s 372ms
>   [ERROR] pod install returned a non-zero exit code

The only change I had to make was to set sdk-version in tiapp.xml to 5.4.0.v20160608165242 instead of 5.4.0 (pulled this version of the SDK by running `appc ti sdk install -b 5_4_X`)

`appc -v` returns 5.2.2
`appc ti -v` returns 5.0.6

Also, if I remove the Podfile file, the app builds and runs on the simulator.  Most of the samples work (obviously not the Third-Party Libraries one).  I see in some of the other issues where people were able to get the cocoapod dependencies working, so this may just be a cocoapod issue with my machine.
`pod --version` returns 1.0.1

`pod install` provides the error:

> Could not automatically select an Xcode project. Specify one in your Podfile like so:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version 1.0.1 of cocoapods does not work with hyperloop right now.  Uninstalled that version and installed 0.39.0 instead resolved the issue.
`sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.39.0`

Comment: According to the latest 5.4.0.GA guide at http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Hyperloop_Programming_Guide version 1.0.1 should now be supported but I am still getting this error.   WiIl try to downgrade as you suggested.

Comment: @Kosso If you have upgraded an existing project to 5.4.0, make sure the plugins/hyperloop folder is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

One way that worked for me:

- Remove cocoapods

  ```
  gem uninstall --all --executables cocoapods
  ```
- Install it again

  ```
  sudo gem install cocoapods
  ```
- Make sure you're running latest node lts (4.5.0)
- Re-open Appc Studio to see it works